Probability of crossing value $N= 1000$ with face $k$ when adding up 6-sided dice rolls? Also two 6-sided dice?
We roll a 6-side die repeatedly until the accumulated sum exceeds $N=1000$. What is the probability that the last roll (last face) equals $k$?
I've tried doing this by hand: We go over 1000 with 1 by rolling a 1 when we have 1000, we go over 1000 with 2 by rolling a 2 when we have 999 or 1000, etc. And so we can proceed to work backwards. But working backwards all the way down to zero would take forever. I wonder if there's a good way to get an estimate, or if there's any way to write a program to solve this.
Also, I'm curious in the analogous question for 2 6-sided dice. Like what's the probability of going over 1000 by rolling a 2, rolling a 3, rolling a 4, rolling a 12 etc.

Your setup is somewhat unclear.  My guess is that you propose rolling a six-sided die, keeping a running sum of the results of throws.  Eventually that sum will surpass $1000$.    The outcome is the value of the final throw, the one that takes the running sum over $1000$.

Please ask only one question per post.  If you have two questions (one about a single die, one about two dice), then ask them separately.  Thank you!

As mentioned in the other answers, there's a recursion you can use to compute the probabilities. To cover both of the problems you ask about, consider the following generalisation. Let the possible values of a throw be $\ t,t+1,\dots,t+m-1 $ with probabilities $\ p_1,p_2,\dots,p_m\ ,$ $\ P_{ns}\ $ the probability that the total thrown after $\ n\ $ throws is $\ s\ $, for $\ s=1,2,\dots,N-1\ ,$ $\ F_{ni}\ $ the probability that the total of $\ N\ $ was reached or surpassed with a throw of $\ t+i-1\ $ on or before the $\ n^\text{th}\ $ throw.  Then
\begin{align}
P_{1 s}&=\cases{p_i&if $\ s=t+i-1$\\
0&otherwise}\\
P_{ns}&=\sum_{i=1}^mp_iP_{n-1\,s-t-i+1}\ \ \text{ for }\ \ 1\le s\le N-1\ ,\ \text{ and}\\
F_{ni}&=p_i\sum_{j=1}^{t+i-1}P_{n-1\,N-j}\ .
\end{align}
Since the total $\ N\ $ must be reached by the $\ L\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\left\lceil\frac{N}{t}\right\rceil^\text{th}\ $ thr0w at the latest, $\ F_{Li}\ $ are the probabilities you're looking for.
I have included below some Magma code to carry out this procedure for the two problems you ask about. You can run it by copying and pasting it into the online Magma calculator and pressing the "submit" button.  For your first problem the code gives results identical to those given in ploosu2's answer.  Note  that the decimal approximations look like they might be periodic with a relatively small period, although this is an illusion. As ploosu2 remarks in his answer, the exact answers are rational numbers with enormous numerators and denominators.   Nevertheless, the rational fractions $\ \frac{1}{21},$$\,\frac{2}{21},$$\,\frac{3}{21},$$\,\frac{4}{21},$$\,\frac{5}{21}\ $ and $\ \frac{6}{21}\ $ do lie within $\ 10^{-137}\ $ of the exact answers. No doubt the explanation for this is that the probabilities converge as the target total is increased from $1000$ towards infinity, and the limits are the relatively simple fractions just listed.
For your second problem, the Magma code produces the following results, given to $20$ or so decimal places in the second column of the following table. Again, the rational approximations in the third column lie within $\ 10^{-92}\ $ of the exact answers.
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline\\
\text{last throw}&\text{approximate probability}&{\hspace{1em}\text{rational}\\\text{approximation}}\\
\hline
2&0.0079365079365079365079&\frac{1}{126}\\
3&0.023809523809523809524&\frac{1}{42}\\
4&0.047619047619047619048&\frac{1}{21}\\
5&0.079365079365079365079&\frac{5}{63}\\
6&0.11904761904761904762&\frac{5}{42}\\
7&0.16666666666666666667&\frac{1}{6}\\
8&0.15873015873015873016&\frac{10}{63}\\
9&0.14285714285714285714&\frac{1}{7}\\
10&0.11904761904761904762&\frac{5}{42}\\
11&0.087301587301587301587&\frac{11}{126}\\
12&0.047619047619047619048&\frac{1}{21}\\
\hline
\end{array}
   getprobs:=function(t,m,p,N);
   oldP:=ZeroMatrix(Rationals(),1,N-1);
   newP:=ZeroMatrix(Rationals(),1,N-1);
   F:=ZeroMatrix(Rationals(),1,m);
   for i in [1..m] do
     oldP[1,t+i-1]:=p[1,i];
   end for;
   L1:=Floor(Rationals()!N/Rationals()!(t+m-1));
   L2:=Ceiling(Rationals()!N/Rationals()!t);
   for i in [1..L1-1] do
      for j in [i*t..i*(t+m-1)] do
          for k in [t..t+m-1] do
            newP[1,j+k]:=newP[1,j+k]+oldP[1,j]*p[1,k+1-t];
          end for;
      end for;
      oldP:=newP;
      newP:=ZeroMatrix(Rationals(),1,N-1);
   end for;

   for i in [L1..L2] do
      for k in [1..m] do
         for s in [1..t+k-1] do
             F[1,k]:=F[1,k]+oldP[1,N-s]*p[1,k];
         end for;
      end for;
      for j in [i*t..Min(i*(t+m-1),N-1)] do
          for k in [t..Min(t+m-1,N-j-1)] do               
            newP[1,j+k]:=newP[1,j+k]+oldP[1,j]*p[1,k-t+1];
          end for;
      end for;
      oldP:=newP;
      newP:=ZeroMatrix(Rationals(),1,N-1);
   end for;      
   return F;
end function;

N:=1000;
t:=1;
m:=6;
p:=ZeroMatrix(Rationals(),1,m);
for i in [1..m] do
   p[1,i]:=1/6;
end for;
F:=getprobs(t,m,p,N);

for i in [1..m] do
   print(RealField(20)!F[1,i]);
end for;

t:=2;
m:=11;
p:=ZeroMatrix(Rationals(),1,m);
for i in [1..m] do
   p[1,i]:=Min(i,12-i)/36;
end for;
F:=getprobs(t,m,p,N);
appf:=Matrix(Rationals(),1,m,[1/126,1/42,1/21,5/63,5/42,1/6,10/63,1/7,5/42,11/126,1/21]);
tot:=0;
for i in [1..m] do;
   tot:=tot+appf[1,i];
   print(t+i-1);
   print(RealField(20)!F[1,i]);
   print(RealField(20)!(F[1,i]-appf[1,i]));
end for;
print(tot);


It's easy to get a quick approximation:
In $m$ tries, we should have aproximately $m/6$ ones, $m/6$ twos, etc. The accumulated number is $ M = \frac{1}{6} (1+2 +\cdots +6)= \frac{m}{6} \frac{6 \cdot 7}{2}$. Hence there are a proportion of $k/21$ positions corresponding to face $k$, and that should correspond to the probabilities of hitting a given target $N$ (the approximation should improve with larger $N$).
If you want an exact result, I think we can devise a recursive numeric algorithm (See @ploosu2's answer for numerical exact solution).
This approximation gives
($0.047619047619$, $0.095238095238$, $ 0.142857142857$, $ 0.190476190476$, $0.238095238095$, $ 0.285714285714$),
quite near the simulation results in the comments - and practically indistinguishable from the exact results from @ploosu2's answer.
This approach can easily be adapted to two dice.
My results:
2   0.0079365079
3   0.0238095238
4   0.0476190476
5   0.0793650794
6   0.1190476190
7   0.1666666667
8   0.1587301587
9   0.1428571429
10  0.1190476190
11  0.0873015873
12  0.0476190476



Here a dynamic programming in Python for the exact result. (Takes about a minute to run). It's basically the recursive idea: we keep as state the current total and the outcome of the previous roll. It yields
$$
(0.047619047619047616, 0.09523809523809523, 0.14285714285714285, 0.19047619047619047, 0.23809523809523808, 0.2857142857142857)
$$
The approximation by leonbloy is extremely accurate. The differences are of order $10^{-138}$. By the way, since the program calculated the answer as a rational number, I checked that the denominator is always $6^{1000}$, there's no cancellation. I wonder if this has something to do with the fact that it must be so close to to the rational number $\frac{k}{21}$ having a $3$ in the denominator. Well, this was just a curiosity.
To modify for the case of $2$ dice, adjust the transitions accordingly.

Regarding the common denominators being $6^{1000}$, one way to think about this is to consider an integer only version of the computation.  We need at most $1000$ throws to reach the threshold, and if we maintain only the state of the running sum up to $1000$ or the "final throw" when $1000$ is surpassed, then each throw splits each previous outcome into six updated outcomes.  So after a thousand throws, the total number of outcomes is $6^{1000}$ and thus that is a common denominator for the probabilities.
